# What's the meaning of all this?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

While playing Arkham Origins, I stumbled on this code.  Unfortunately, I have completely forgotten where I was at in the game so I cannot provide the location that this screenshot was taken at.

[image: Computer terminal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When translated to ASCII characters, the hexadecimal shown in that screenshot translates to:

> Joining the GCPD was the easiest thing I ever did. I will find out all of their dirty little secrets. By the time they know what I know, it will be too late. This is only the beginning.

Sources: [[1]](http://www.reddit.com/r/arkhamgames/comments/1r08y5/enigmas_hex_message/), [[2]](http://community.wbgames.com/t5/General-Discussion/Easter-Eggs-and-References-SPOILERS/m-p/74933#M16612)

Comment: I figured it was HEX values, so I went through and decoded while waiting for an answer.  My output matches this one.  Thanks for the links.